# How to remove "horizontal scroll bar" of one or more entry in collectionview?

Tags: android, xamarin, collectionview

I have updated a Xamarin Forms proyect to 4.2 and I'm usign a CollectionView with an entry for each data template. The "problem" is that when I tap on a entry I get a weird little underline under all the entries in the list.

Honestly I don't know from where this underline is come from!

[image: the underline]
Here you can see a little grey underline under the "00"

EDIT:

I have discovered that is a small horizontal scroll bar, here I have created another collection view (yeah, the binding is totally random, but I want a fast example) and I have set HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Never" but it is still showed (it's a CollectionView property not entry...).

Code:

```
<StackLayout>
    <CollectionView x:Name="ItemsListView"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
                    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                    HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Never"
                    ItemsUpdatingScrollMode="KeepScrollOffset">
        <d:CollectionView.ItemsSource>
            <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
                <x:String>First Item</x:String>
                <x:String>Second Item</x:String>
                <x:String>Third Item</x:String>
                <x:String>Fourth Item</x:String>
                <x:String>Fifth Item</x:String>
                <x:String>Sixth Item</x:String>
            </x:Array>
        </d:CollectionView.ItemsSource>
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackLayout>
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"
                                 BackgroundColor="AntiqueWhite"
                                 Padding="10"
                                 Margin="10">
                        <Entry WidthRequest="50" />
                        <Entry WidthRequest="50" />
                    </StackLayout>
                </StackLayout>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
</StackLayout>
```

[image: collection view with entries]

There is a way to remove it? or at least make it appears only in the entry selected?

P.S. I think I haven't mentioned it, it appears only for some second (when tap on an entry) and then disappears.

Comment: could you show your codes?Then could find the issue more accurately

Comment: you could check below,could it work ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use custom render to custom the entry,for example:

custom an Entry **MyEntry** :

```
public class MyEntry :Entry
{
}
```

then in Android project,create a entry render **AndroidEntry** :

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MyEntry), typeof(AndroidEntry))]
namespace App18.Droid
{
  class AndroidEntry:EntryRenderer
   {
     public AndroidEntry(Context context) : base(context)
      {
      }
     protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
      {
          base.OnElementChanged(e);
          if (Control !=null)
           {
             Control.SetSingleLine(true);
             Control.HorizontalScrollBarEnabled = false;
           }
      }
   }
}
```

then in axml use your custom entry :

```
<CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
       <StackLayout>
         <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"
             BackgroundColor="AntiqueWhite"
             Padding="10"
             Margin="10">
            <local:MyEntry WidthRequest="50" />
            <local:MyEntry WidthRequest="50" />
         </StackLayout>
       </StackLayout>
    </DataTemplate>
</CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1):

Leo's solution is great, but it is an overuse of CustomRenderers in my opinion. This is not something you use a CustomRenderer for.

An Effect is more than enough to achieve what you want - and is reusable across other types.

Create a NoHorizontalScrollbarEffect.cs file in your shared project:

```
namespace YourAppName.Effects 
{
    public class NoHorizontalScrollbarEffect : RoutingEffect
    {
        public NoHorizontalScrollbarEffect() : base($"MyApp.{nameof(NoHorizontalScrollbarEffect)}")
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Note that "MyApp" above and below need to match but it can be any kind of text.

Now add NoHorizontalScrollbarEffect_Android.cs in the corresponding platform-specific project:

```
[assembly: ResolutionGroupName("MyApp")]
[assembly: ExportEffect(typeof(NoHorizontalScrollbarEffect), nameof(NoHorizontalScrollbarEffect))]
namespace YourAppName.Android.Effects
{
    public class NoHorizontalScrollbarEffect : PlatformEffect
    {
        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            Android.Views.View view = this.Control ?? this.Container //Control is null for Layouts
            view.HorizontalScrollBarEnabled = false;
        }

        protected override void OnDetached()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

And then you can use this effect on any XAML element deriving from View (including Entry) after adding the `xmlns:effects="clr-namespace:YourAppName.Effects"` (the namespace of the shared project's Effect class) at the top of the page:

```
...
<AnyControl ...>
    ...
    <AnyControl.Effects>
         <effects:NoHorizontalScrollbarEffect />
    </AnyControl.Effects>
</AnyControl>
...
```

Comment: I think it is not working on mobile apps.